# How do we prove that $g(x,y) = 1 + \theta[xe^{-x} - (1-\frac{2}{e})][ye^{-y} - (1-\frac{2}{e})]\geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, derivatives, probability-distributions

Consider the following bivariate density function:

$$\displaystyle g(x,y) = 1 + \theta\left[xe^{-x} - \left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right)\right]\left[ye^{-y} - \left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right)\right]$$

where $(x,y)\in[0,1]^{2}$ and $\theta\in[-1,1]$.

How can we show that it is non-negative based on the analysis of its critical points? To be more precise, its critical points are given by $(1,1)$ and $(0.3904,0.3904)$.

Doing some analysis, we conclude that $g(1,1)$ is a maximum point and $(0.3904,0.3904)$ is a saddle point. Moreover, we also have to study its behavior on the border, from whence we find that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are critical points as well (both maximum points).

From now on I get a little lost. Based on such results, how do we conclude that $g(x,y) \geq 0$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get $(0.3904, 0.3904)$ as a critical point?

Comment: From numerical methods applied to to $(g_{x},g_{y}) = (0,0)$.

Comment: that makes it a zero-crossing (a.k.a. root) in a sense, but how does that make it a critical point?

Comment: It is a saddle point, since its hessian is negative.

Comment: oh!!  haha, now i see why it is a saddle point, but IMHO it's completely irrelevant to your problem.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to prove this. First observe that the minimum w.r.t. $\theta$is attained at $\pm 1$ so what is stated is equivalent to $|xe^{-x} -(1-\frac  2 e)||ye^{-y} -(1-\frac  2 e)|\leq 1$. Let us prove that $|xe^{-x} -(1-\frac  2 e)|\leq 1$ and $|ye^{-y} -(1-\frac  2 e)|\leq 1$. For this just note that $xe^{-x} -(1-\frac  2 e)$ has positive derivative on $[0,1]$ so it is an increasing function. Its extrema are at the end points $x=0$ and $x=1$. At these two points it is trivial to verify the inequality, so we are done.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the contribution. But could you explain why the proposed method works?

Comment: The minimum value is attained at the border points. You just have to verify the inequality at the points where $x,y\in \{0,1\}, \theta \in \{-1,1\}$ which is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS (in case this is homework)

- Define $f(z) = z e^{-z}$ with domain $z \in [0,1]$.  Within this domain, if my own calculations are not buggy, you can show that $f$ is increasing.
- Find range of $f(z)$ for $z \in [0,1]$.
- Use it to find range of $[f(x) - a] [f(y) - a]$ for $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ where $a = (1 - 2/e)$.
- Finally you can prove that, for any $\theta, x, y$ in their respective domains, $g(x,y,\theta) = 1 + \theta [f(x) - a] [f(y) - a] \ge 0$.

Hopefully this recipe works for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not a homework. I am interested in the proposed procedure because it is related to an article I am studying.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Why don't you try the recipe and see if it works for you.  For bullet $1$ I used $f'(z)$ and that is when I start questioning why $0.3904$ is critical.